# Power Bi DAX: Static Data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a little problem i need fixing.

In my PBIX file i have had teams as a slicer that filter my data, but new teams have been made and taken projects from other teams to even the work load.

My question is that, can i make all data from before the teams were introduced to 0. My data is being shown from a six month period, new teams were made last month so everything before Jan should be 0 as they have had done no work since then.

is it possible to make their data 0 without removing the data from the data-source?

Apologies if this is very vague, it is private information.

I am happy to make a dummy sheet for you.

Comment: by default, when you select a team that has no data prior to certain date it will just show `BLANK`. Do you want to replace `BLANK` with `0`s?

Comment: Each time has people under them which all have projects with data, after they became team leaders they took those people into their team. How can i take out the data from their teams before they became leaders? so from december back, it will show as 0 but will still have January data.

Comment: if you have a timestamp/flag showing when a person had became a team leader then it should be easy. Can you share a dummy sheet in format that can be copied to PowerBi without typing?

Comment: All i have done is make bar charts that have the period from Aug 19 - Jan 20 (Last 6 Months) and the value being KPI info like Net Value, Invoicing and other areas like meeting, calls etc. all the values are linked people that are under the leaders. Can i remove the data from a date based on a person?

Comment: you need to create measures with `CALCULATE` that would filter out new team leaders. I cannot help more without sample data